# Is the following series uniformly convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Is the series ‎$‎\sum_{n=1}^\infty‎\frac{2(n+x)}{((n+x)^2+1)^2}$‎ uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$?

Comment: what do you think? what have you tried?

Comment: I think that, it is uniformly convergent with using comparisons test But I do not know how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to show what you intended or how you wanted to proceed.

Majoring numerator and minoring denominator gives

$$
2\frac{n+x}{\left(\left(n+x\right)^2+1\right)^2} \leq 2\frac{n+1}{\left(1+n^2\right)^2}\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{2}{n^3}
$$
And $\displaystyle \sum_{ n \geq 1}^{ }\frac{1}{n^3}$ converges so the series is normally hence uniformly convergent on $\left[0,1\right]$.

Indeed 
$$
\left|\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}2\frac{n+x}{\left(\left(n+x\right)^2+1\right)^2}\right| \leq \sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}\underset{x \in \left[0,1\right]}{\text{sup}}\left(2\frac{n+x}{\left(\left(n+x\right)^2+1\right)^2}\right)\leq 2\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$$
The rest of a convergent series tend to  $0$ hence
$$
\underset{x \in \left[0,1\right]}{\text{sup}}\left|\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}2\frac{n+x}{\left(\left(n+x\right)^2+1\right)^2}\right|\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$